# Do I need to use sessions in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, session

Or in PHP in general. I need to check if a user is logged in when accessing a certain page. Tutorials recommend using sessions e.g

```
$sessionData = array('username'=>$username, 'status'=>1);
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
```

And for better security they recommend using a db table.

What if I just store username and status in a database and then change status to 0 when people log out?

Whenever they need access to a certain page I just check if the status 1.

Comment: How would you know they logged out?

Comment: "Whenever they need access to a certain page I just check if the status 1."  When multiple people try to access that page, how do you know who is who? Sessions are very easy to work with and useful for more than just testing if a user is logged in. I recommend getting comfortable with using them.

Comment: If you're not using sessions how can you determine the user that is logged in, is who they say he is? You'll have to use something in terms of session to keep the user alive, when he changes pages you'll have no reference to who the user is.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you call `session_start()` PHP sets a cookie in the user's browser with a randomly-generated ID.
2. From then on in that file anytime you store a value in `$_SESSION` will [by default] be stored in a file in `session.save_path` at the end of the script. This file is identified by the session ID.
3. On subsequent requests the client sends their session ID cookie back to the server, so when you call `session_start()` in your script PHP can go and retrieve that session file and restore the contents to `$_SESSION`.

Literally anything *you* will write will simply be re-implementing this already-written behaviour, but without the added layers of security contributed over the years to the PHP project.

Comment: Thanks. I know how sessions work in PHP and CI. Im just asking whats the point of using them.